# Cannot create instance of class when grouping in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I am having trouble inheriting classes when grouping swift files.
For example if the file structure is like below I am able to inherit Test object.

```
test
|-Test.swift
|-ViewController
```

However if I group the swift file then I am not able to create a instance giving me an error saying `Use of unresolved identifier 'Test’`

```
test
|-Model
    |-Test.swift
|-ViewController
```

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let test = Test()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
}
```

Test

```
public struct Test {
    var frameRate = 0.0
    var name: String?
}
```

I did not have this previously. Did something change starting from Xcode 11?

Comment: Make sure `Test.swift` file is added in target membership

Comment: Thank you however yes I have already checked the target.

Comment: close and reopen Xcode. and build your project. this seems like an Xcode issue. restarting might work.

Comment: @KeshuRai What!!! Thank you !! Unbelievable...

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer or delete your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments this is a bug in Xcode 11. The fix is to close and reopen Xcode. and build your project. restarting might work too